# Ember contextual component list

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know if there a way in Ember to have to a parent component keep reference to all contextual components initialized

For example:

In this parent component would have array of 2 child components.

```
{{checkbox-group value=value sortBy="name" as |group|}}
   {{group.checkbox}}
   {{group.checkbox}}
{{/checkbox-group}}
```

Comment: You can't sort inserted child component. Just maybe with jquery (messy work). I think if you pass a data object like array to your checkbox-group and let it sort and create child components internally fits your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, somehow you can do it.

In your parent components template:

```
{{yield (hash child=(component 'my-child' registerFunction=(action registerFunction)))}}
```

In your `init` method of `my-child` component, call `registerFunction`.

But I strongly believe that *keeping reference to the components from parent component* is a code smell.

Comment: Thanks, Its possible I am not thinking this correctly. Essentially I would like create a checkbox-group component that you could sort the checkbox component embedded inside

Comment: You can do it. Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/df3ce36f68fcacfa3785138256edf16d?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-group.hbs).

Comment: But putting *the responsibility of sorting* in checkbox-group component can be another smell.